# lua table addressing

Tags: lua

I have a table `logTable = {["cdm"] = "log text", ["data_engine"] = "log text"}`

The code:

```
for k,v in pairs(logTable) do
    print(v["cdm"]) end
```

Gives the desired result: log text

However

```
print(logTable["cdm"])
```

returns nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

So this is actually how I am making the table:

```
table.insert(logTable, { [probeName] = file.read('export/'..robotName..'/probes/'..probeGroup..'/'..probeName..'/'..probeName..'.log')})
```

Where probeName is a variable, could it be that I need to `["probeName"]` to make it a string? However this takes it as a literal and not a variable?

How can I use a variable as table index/key

Comment: Your example code works fine. http://codepad.org/n8z78Bae There must be something different going on in your actual code?

Comment: So this is actually how I am making the table:

table.insert(logTable, { [probeName] = file.read('export/'..robotName..'/probes/'..probeGroup..'/'..probeName..'/'..probeName..'.log')}) 

Where probeName is a variable, could it be that I need to ["probeName"] to make it a string? However this takes it as a literal and not a variable? 

How can I use a variable as table index/key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a table *inside* a table here, so your table looks like this:

```
{
    { 
      ["cdm"] = "log text",
      ["data engine"] = "log text"
    }
}
```

That's why your `print(logTable["cdm"])` doesn't work. `table.insert` is also meant to be used with number-indexed tables; this time, the dictionary syntax is clearer:

```
logTable["probeName"] = file.read('export/'..robotName..
                                  '/probes/'..probeGroup..'/'
                                  ..probeName..'/'..probeName..'.log')
```

Comment: In the latter case `logTable["probeName"]` can be also written as `logTable.probeName`. Unless you actually want to use the value of `probeName` variable, in which case you should use just `logTable[probeName]`.