# LUA Variables as Table Keys

Tags: lua

I create and populate a table:

table.insert(logTable, { [probeName] = "log text" }

Is that the correct way to use a variable in the [key] section?

I am thinking lua is interprating this as an integer rather than a string?

Comment: see also the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359227/lua-table-addressing/11360021#11360021

Answer (score 5):

**{ [probeName] = "log text" }** will create a literal table indexed by the value of variable probeName. So it will depend on that value's type. It could be an integer, or a string, or a function or table etc.

So:

```
probeName = 'abc'
for k, v in pairs({ [probeName] = "log text" }) do print(type(k), k, v) end
probeName = 123
for k, v in pairs({ [probeName] = "log text" }) do print(type(k), k, v) end
probeName = { 'another table' }
for k, v in pairs({ [probeName] = "log text" }) do print(type(k), k, v) end
```

Produces output:

```
string  abc log text
number  123 log text
table   table: 0xfa6050 log text
```

Now, **table.insert(logTable, { [probeName] = "log text" }** will actually take that literal table and insert it into another table (logTable) with integer index. So logTable will contain a bunch of integer-indexed table entries, which each have a single value (log text) which is keyed by some value (probeName). Iterate over it with **ipairs**. If rather you wished to accumulate all the logs by probe name into one table, you need to do something like **logTable[probeName] = "log text"** which is actually simpler. Iterate over it with **pairs**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If `probeName` is a number, Lua will interpret it as such, but it *won't* convert a string containing digits to a number. If it is a number and you want to convert it to a string, you can use coercion (`["" .. probeName]`) or string formatting (`[string.format("%d", probeName)]`).

Comment: The function you're looking for is aptly named `tostring`.